# Microsoft Edge WebView2 - The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, wpf, webviewchromium, webview2

This post is about [Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) control. When working on `WebView2WpfBrowser` sample from github [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples), I get the following error at the following code in file `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file. The sample runs fine except when in the the `address bar` I type a URL and click on `Go` button next to the address bar. URL I had typed was `Microsoft.com`:

**Error**:

> > System.UriFormatException
> > HResult=0x80131537
> > Message=Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
> > Source=System.Private.Uri

**Code**:

```
void GoToPageCmdExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webView.Source = new Uri((string)e.Parameter);
}
```

**Question**: What could be the cause of the error, and how can it be fixed?

**UPDATE**:

Just noticed that the error occurs if you don't type the `full URL format` (e.g. `https://www.microsoft.com/`). It throws the above error if you, for example, just type `microsoft.com` or even `www.microsoft.com`.

So now, instead of a question, it's probably a bug report.

Comment: Yes, just add `http://` or `https://`. This is normal for `WebView` and `WebView2`

Comment: The question is: Should it add 'http' or 'https' (or even 'file') ? Very different.  It has no way of knowing, so you must add it yourself.

Comment: For a bug report, please open an Issue in our feedback repo: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback